# Silverlight 3.0 writableBitmap

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

i have a writableBitmap object which i want to save on server. Is there any way to save it may be using webservice??

Comment: Question isn't clear enough to understand the anticipated answer: this is a yes/no question really in this state.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send the `byte[]` as a Stream to your own web service, or serialize it and send it however, wherever, you like.